# memset() in C not initialising to a const double;

Tags: c, memset

Hi I have the following code written in C for x86,

```
const double N = 4;
const double C = 1.0 / N; <---- 0.2500

double *array = (double*)calloc(10, sizeof(double));

memset(array, C, 10);
```

the result of the memset only returns 0.0000 for each element instead of the value stored in C..

can anyone please help?

Comment: “The memset() function fills the first n bytes of the memory area pointed to by s with the constant byte c.” A `double` is not a byte.

Comment: is there no way to store double?

Comment: You can loop manually.

Comment: would there be any trade offs in terms of the time if I decide to loop it manually?

Comment: There might be, although I would think the trade-off of working versus not working was a more important one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`memset` initializes a block of memory with a given byte value.  Bytes are `unsigned char`, a much smaller unit than `double` which uses 8 bytes on your architecture.  Unless all the bytes of the `double` value `C` are identical, `memset` cannot be used to initialize an array of `double` values. On IEEE-754 compliant systems such as the various x86 variants, `+0.0` has all bytes with all bits `0`, so you could use `memset(array[i], 0, 10 * sizeof(double))` to initialize the array to `0.0`, but this is neither readable nor portable.  For most other values, It not possible at all.

You must use a simple `for` loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    array[i] = C;
```

The loop will be optimized by the compiler, especially if C is a compile time constant.

Answer (score -4):

```
void *memset(void *s, int c, size_t n);
```

[memset](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/memset.3.html) accepts an int or a constant byte to fill the memory.

*The value provide by you is a `double`. So how `memset` is going to deal with it ?*

> The value provided by you will be **implicitly casted to int and then
>   the casted value will again be casted to unsigned char to get a byte
>   value**.

Also, the size_t argument of memset is the number of bytes. You should use, `10 * sizeof(double)` instead of just `10`.

Comment: Your explanation is somewhat confusing: memory is not *filled with const double C but casted to int*.  And the OP cannot confirm anything by using another double value, he probably has an inadequate understanding of how memory is organized.  Even the compiler warning is confusing: `int array[10]; memset(array, 123456789, 10);` will compile without a warning but fail to accomplish the goal by a long shot.

Comment: *filling your memory with value 5* is correct at the byte level, but the memory is accessed as `double`, the OP will still not understand your explanation and cannot verify the value `5`, not to mention the size argument that is `10` instead of `10 * sizeof(double)`.

Comment: @chqrlie:: I think, it's pretty less-confusing now. The warning is self-explanatory.

Comment: As I explained in my previous comment, the warning is confusing because it only pertains to prototype for `memset` taking an `int` for historical reasons, and not to its semantics which you correctly explained.  Regarding the effect of `memset` on an array of `double`, your explanation is partial.  I'm obviously not the only one to consider it inadequate.